# Security issues in html markups based relying on jquery and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

How my markup created by html and jquery be secure. For an instance I have one button which may have some decisive action say 'Withdraw Money'. If I hide that button for particular user by css property `display:none`. If some of user come and using developers tools and enable button by `display:block`. And he can easily do the action as he required. How can we provide security in that context?. Is there any way to encrypt markup?.

Please assist. Welcome for any suggestions.

Comment: You do not have to secure the client-side markup that triggers the action, but the server-side handling of it – check there whether the user is entitled to take that action or not. And make yourself aware that a request reaching your server might not even come from a “browser” at all.

Answer (score 0):

1) disable the button by setting a new action like `function(){};` and set it when he should be enabled
2) block it on the server implementation. Javascript is not save for secure things, because the user can modify it.

Comment: Do not get 'disable the button by setting a new action like function(){};'. Please elaborate.

Comment: `function activate() { 
   $('#button').click(
   function()
     {/* do secret things*/}
   )};
function deactivate() { 
    $('#button').click(
    function()
        {/* do nothing*/}
    )}
`